# Retrieve latest topic of subcategory

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve the latest topic of an subcategory.
Here is my SQL:

```
    SELECT * FROM threads
LEFT JOIN subs 
ON subs.category_id = threads.subcategory_id
LEFT JOIN categories 
ON categories.id = subs.category_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(lastdate) lastdate
    FROM threads
    GROUP BY id
) b ON subs.category_id = threads.subcategory_id AND threads.lastdate = b.lastdate
GROUP BY subs.category_id, threads.subcategory_id, threads.lastdate DESC
```

However, if I am trying to make an thread with an subcategory which links to an category which is used twice, it doesn't work.

Maybe someone can help me out.

Subs in database:
[image: http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/2016/08/01/0017/1178/1131674/74/78baa81e01.png]
(as you can see, some of the subcategories has the same category_id

Updated query. It now duplicate the echo output for each new category linked to an category which is used twice:
http://joxi.ru/DmBJzQ5c1Ll0mP

Comment: Update your question to explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: If I add an record to my database in threads which has an subcategory_id  that uses an category id which is used twice in subs, it doesn't show the result.

Comment: Update the question with an example of that please.  Also provide the definition for your categories and threads tables.

Comment: Some images and extra explanation has added.

Comment: That group by in the outer query makes no sense

Comment: It does. Updated question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resulting data on last thread\_date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525618/resulting-data-on-last-thread-date)