# Resulting data on last thread_date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

As I fixed the previous question thanks to the answer, I am sticking now in the part to retrieve a thread based on the last thread_date.

The code itself seems to be working fine, but it is only printing one result out instead of others.

The thread has a threads.cat_id which is linked to thesubsubcategory.extra_cat_id.

```
SELECT 
parent.subcat_id, 
parent.subcat_name, 
child.subsubcat_name, 
child.subcat_id, 
child.cat_id, 
kid.thread_name, 
kid.cat_id, 
kid.thread_date 
FROM 
subcategories parent  
JOIN subsubcategories child 
ON child.cat_id = parent.cat_id
 JOIN threads kid ON child.extra_cat_id = kid.cat_id 
WHERE thread_date = (SELECT MAX(thread_date) FROM threads)
```

**What I am expecting is this:**

```
 Category
    Subcategory       Latest thread
    Subcategory       Latest thread
```

**What I am getting is this:**

```
Category
  Subcategory       Latest thread
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52e27/2

Any solutions to it?

Thanks!

Comment: You are filtering the output with your where clause, adjust that to your need.

Comment: mysql?? or sql server?

Comment: The driver I am using is Postgresql.

Comment: Made an SQLFiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52e27/2

Comment: Can anyone please argue the downvotes?

Comment: How about using a GroupBy on the id of your parent?

Comment: Daar ga ik eens naar kijken, dank! Gonna take a look at that, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got this fixed by creating a PHP function to return the latest thread with a

`SELECT * FROM threads WHERE subcat_id = variable` SQL.

Comment: Errrrrrrrr what? This is a way most forum systems does, so why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is right, you want to edit the where clause to show more based on last date as your threaddate is a datetime, you have to convert it to a date format before comparing it.

```
    SELECT parent.subcat_id,
        parent.subcat_name,
        child.subsubcat_name,
        child.subcat_id,
        child.cat_id,
        kid.thread_name,
        kid.cat_id,
        kid.thread_date
    FROM subcategories parent
    INNER JOIN subsubcategories child
        ON child.cat_id = parent.cat_id
    INNER JOIN threads kid
        ON child.extra_cat_id = kid.cat_id
WHERE convert(date,thread_date,108) = (
        SELECT MAX(convert(date,thread_date,108))
        FROM threads
        )
```

Comment: Nope, that's not what I really want. I want to show the latest thread based on the thread_date (which isn't a date atm) per subcategory (which is subsubcategory in the SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to get a thread with maximal date for every subsubcategory, don't you?

```
SELECT
  parent.subcat_id,
  parent.subcat_name,
  child.subsubcat_name,
  child.subcat_id,
  child.cat_id,
  kid.thread_name,
  kid.cat_id,
  kid.thread_date
FROM subcategories parent
  JOIN subsubcategories child ON child.cat_id=parent.cat_id
  JOIN threads kid ON kid.cat_id=child.extra_cat_id
WHERE kid.thread_date=
  (SELECT MAX(kid2.thread_date)
   FROM threads kid2
   WHERE kid2.cat_id=child.extra_cat_id)
```

Comment: That is duplicating the category names.

Comment: @user6632515, what do you mean? Are there some subcategories which have more than one corresponding subsubcategories? In this case subcat_id and subcat_name of such subcategories will repeat in appropriate amount of rows and it would be exaclly what you need.

Comment: Yes - there are more subsubcategories linked to a same subcategory. Any idea's to do this?